# Returning a response immediately with res.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have an express route which takes in some parameters, queries the database, and then returns some response.

I am using sequelize to query the db:

```
router.get('/query', function(req,res) {
    var name = req.params.name;
    var gid = req.params.gid;

    // Query the db
    models.user.find({ where: { name: name }}).then(function(user) {
        models.group.find({ where: { id: gid }}).then(function(group) {
            // if user found, return data to client
            if (user) {
                res.json({"user": user, "group": group});
            }
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // catch any errors from db query
        res.status(500).json({"error":error});
    }); 


    // Return a server error for any other reason
    // This causes ERROR
    res.status(500).json({"error":"Something went wrong. Check your input."});    
});
```

But I keep getting the error on the last line:

```
Can't set headers after they are sent
```

It seems like the last line is ALWAYS run, even if it finds a user (which should return data to the client and be done).

Why doesn't `res.json(..)` immediately return to the client when a user is found? Since headers were already set, when the last line runs, it throws that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to only conditionally return an error. The line:

```
res.status(500).json({"error":"Something went wrong. Check your input."});
```

is always getting executed. The reason for this is that the function you pass to the find method is only called later in the event loop after the db responds. This means that when that call back is called you have already set the error on the response.

Your should either remove that line or decide when you want to return an error but don't return an error every time.

Comment: What would be a good way to return some default response if I forget to handle some condition?

Comment: Since node.js is callback based for any long running tasks you cannot simply put everything in a big try catch block as you might in Java. You are already returning an error in the catch callback. That will be the response if anything goes wrong in the find call. I think you are already doing all that you need to. Just delete the line.

Answer (score 0):

Remember javascript is asynchronous.

As soon you call this function

```
models.user.find({ where: { name: name }})
```

That last line is executed:

```
res.status(500).json({"error":"Something went wrong. Check your input."});
```

It seems you are trying to cater for 2 scenarios:

1. Bad request data from client - i.e. no gid given
2. Internal server errors - i.e. error with the database

I would recommend changing your catch function to something like this:

```
.catch(function(error) {
    // catch any errors from db query
    if (err === "Unable to connect to database") {
       return res.status(500).json({ error: "There was an internal error"})
    }

    res.status(400).json({"error": "Bad input, please ensure you sent all required data" });
});
```

Have a read up on the list of standard HTTP status codes:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 0):

What @bhspencer said is right. You have to remove that last line.

That line probably gets executed before any query in the database.

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement a `return` in

`models.user.find({ where: { name: name }}).then(function(user) {
        models.group.find({ where: { id: gid }}).then(function(group) {
            // if user found, return data to client
            if (user) {
                res.json({"user": user, "group": group});
                return;
            }
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // catch any errors from db query
        res.status(500).json({"error":error});
        return;
    });`

Actually `res.json(` does not end the processing of node.js code execution without `return` statement.